# Are there practical size limitations to "compiled" resource files generated by PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyrcc

I've been trying to bundle up some splash screens into a resource file (three of them, at around 350KB each) using pyrcc, but the resulting rc takes an unacceptable amount of time to import (about 1.2 seconds).

I assume this is just a limitation of python's import system, as it doesn't usually have to, nor should it have to, import such a gigantic source file (5MB file, 72k lines).  Am I thinking about this problem the right way?  Is there a way to skirt around PyQt's qrc-to-module workflow while still maintaining all assets in the resource system?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Using three 500Kb images, I created a 6.5Mb resource module. On linux, importing this module takes about 0.15sec on the first pass, and only about 0.025sec thereafter (due to file caching).

Comment: Hmm, I'll try it out on my linux box and see if it makes a difference.  This is currently running on Windows 7, python27

Comment: The module is mostly just one huge byte-string. Importing it shouldn't be much different than just opening the file and reading it into a variable. And indeed if I do that, the timimgs are almost identical. So, on the face of it, 1.2 seconds to import/read a 5Mb module seems a little odd.